# Power Automate Add new role definition using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I'm trying to create a create role definitions i.e. custom permission level using Power Automate with below body in **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint**:

```
{
    'request': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.RoleDefinition' }, 'BasePermissions': 
    { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.BasePermissions' }, 'High': '176' , 'Low': '138612801' }, 
    'Description': 'New description', 'Name': 'New role', 'Order': 180 }
}
```

Below is error:

> An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Body, use the Json below:

```
{
'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.RoleDefinition' },
  'BasePermissions': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.BasePermissions' }, 'High': '176', 'Low': '138612801' },
  'Description': 'New Permission Level Description',
  'Name': 'New Permission Level',
  'Order': 180
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: will check and let you know, thanks

Comment: Is there any update ? Have you tried this in Power Automate ?

Comment: awesome its working